# can you wait for multiple events in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

I am trying to wait for multiple events for my bot, I did find a way and it worked, but then all of a sudden it broke with no errors for no reason

```py
while True:
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
        [
            bot.wait_for("raw_reaction_add")
            bot.wait_for("raw_reacion_remove")
        ]
    )

    payload = done.pop().result()
    if payload.event_type == "REACTION_ADD":
        ...
    elif payload.event_type == "REACTION_REMOVE":
        ...

    for future in pending:
        future.cancel()
```

doing this in my main command is not working, but I made a test command with everything being the same and it's working with no issues

Comment: could you use an on_reaction_add event?

Comment: this is in a command, bot events are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use normal bot events with `on_reaction_add` and `on_reacion_remove` or their raw versions to accomplish this. To share data between each other you could use a database such as MongoDB/pymongo or MySQL/sqlite.

If you are using this command for a reaction role then a database would be a better option to use with the main bot event.

This would make it much easier to debug in the future.

Comment: I am using bot.wait_for() because I need it in a command, but as I said above: "I did find a way and it worked, but then all of a sudden it broke with no errors for no reason"

Comment: It is recommended you don't use it unless you need to edit it at the same time

Comment: I think I should've said that a while ago, but nvm. This chunk of code is used for an interactive setup, I don't think using "@bot.event" rather than "bot.wait_for()" will help

Comment: it is like pagination but when you remove your reaction, something happens

Comment: That is usually done by on_reaction_add. You can do this by storing the message id of the message you want to change and just adding/removing reactions from that